# Coldfusion function within conditional logic

Tags: coldfusion

I am having an issue with functions inside my cfc. They are acting funny when I try to introduce conditional logic to assign a query to the grid. Basically in the URL I will have `?GRIDID=x` and it will tell the cfc which function to run, but when I nest the closing `cffunction` tag inside of the if statements, it throws an error. Here is the code.

```
<cffunction name="grabInfo" access="remote" output="false" returntype="any">
  <cfargument name="page" required="yes">
  <cfargument name="pageSize" required="yes">
  <cfargument name="gridsortcolumn" required="yes">
  <cfargument name="gridsortdirection" required="yes">
  <cfargument name="filtercolumn" required="no" default="">
  <cfargument name="filter" required="no" default="">
  <cfargument name="gridID" required="yes">
    <cfif arguments.gridsortcolumn eq "">
      <cfset arguments.gridsortcolumn = "PatientsName" />
      <cfset arguments.gridsortdirection = "asc" />
    </cfif>



<cfif ARGUMENTS.gridID EQ "1">
  <cfquery name="x" datasource="#dsn#">
    <!--- .... --->
  </cfquery>
<cfreturn QueryConvertForGrid(qGrabInfo, Arguments.page, Arguments.pagesize)>
</cffunction>
</cfif>

<cfif ARGUMENTS.gridID EQ "2">
<cfquery name="x" datasource="#dsn#">
    <!--- .... --->
  </cfquery>
<cfreturn QueryConvertForGrid(qGrabInfo, Arguments.page, Arguments.pagesize)>
</cffunction>
</cfif>
```

This will give me the error `Context validation error for the cfif tag.` but as you can see, all the cfif statements are closed. If I take the first argument and place it with the closing `cffunction` tag outside of the if statement it will work, like so

```
<cfif ARGUMENTS.gridID EQ "1">
  <cfquery name="x" datasource="#dsn#">
    <!--- .... --->
  </cfquery>
<cfreturn QueryConvertForGrid(qGrabInfo, Arguments.page, Arguments.pagesize)>

</cfif>

<cfif ARGUMENTS.gridID EQ "2">
<cfquery name="x" datasource="#dsn#">
    <!--- .... --->
  </cfquery>
<cfreturn QueryConvertForGrid(qGrabInfo, Arguments.page, Arguments.pagesize)>

</cfif>
</cffunction>
```

The reason I need to do this is because I need several other functions run when GridID EQ 2 as well, so I need to close the function and open another as follows

```
<cfif ARGUMENTS.gridID EQ "2">
<cfquery name="x" datasource="#dsn#">
    <!--- .... --->
  </cfquery>
<cfreturn QueryConvertForGrid(qGrabInfo, Arguments.page, Arguments.pagesize)>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="otherFunction">
    <!--- .... --->
</cffunction>
</cfif>
```

Comment: *The reason I need to do this* No, you don't ;-). You are confusing function declaration and usage. The component's functions should be defined up front - not conditionally ie within a `cfif` statement. Use `cfif` to control which of the functions you want to *invoke*, and when.

Answer (score 6):

Add additional functions in your component.

```
<cffunction name="grabInfo" access="remote" output="false" returntype="any">
  <cfargument name="page" required="yes">
  <cfargument name="pageSize" required="yes">
  <cfargument name="gridsortcolumn" required="yes">
  <cfargument name="gridsortdirection" required="yes">
  <cfargument name="filtercolumn" required="no" default="">
  <cfargument name="filter" required="no" default="">
  <cfargument name="gridID" required="yes">
  <cfif arguments.gridsortcolumn eq "">
    <cfset arguments.gridsortcolumn = "PatientsName" />
    <cfset arguments.gridsortdirection = "asc" />
  </cfif>

  <cfif ARGUMENTS.gridID EQ "1">
    <cfquery name="x" datasource="#dsn#">
      <!--- .... --->
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn QueryConvertForGrid(qGrabInfo, Arguments.page, Arguments.pagesize)>
  </cfif>

  <cfif ARGUMENTS.gridID EQ "2">
    <cfquery name="x" datasource="#dsn#">
      <!--- .... --->
    </cfquery>
    <!--- call your other functions --->
    <cfset otherFunction(arg1, arg2)>
    <cfset anotherFunction(arg1, arg2)>
    <cfreturn QueryConvertForGrid(qGrabInfo, Arguments.page, Arguments.pagesize)>
  </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

New functions in same component

```
<cffunction name="otherFunction" access="remote" output="false" returntype="any">
  <cfargument name="arg1">
  <cfargument name="arg2">
  <!--- do things --->
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="anotherFunction" access="remote" output="false" returntype="any">
  <cfargument name="arg1">
  <cfargument name="arg2">
  <!--- do things --->
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 6):

The chief problem you have is a lack of understanding how code compiles. Your code is not executed at runtime, which is when stuff like conditions are evaluated, it needs to be compiled first. And to be compiled, the code needs to be syntactically valid. Which yours is not.

Functions are discrete units of processing, and need to be self contained. What you're trying to do makes absolutely no sense at all from a code perspective. It also demonstrates a lack of understanding of how functions work. They do not execute when they are declared (ie: the `<cffunction>`/`</cffunction>` block, they run when they're *called*.

Matt has got you on the right track, but to reiterate, **you don't do this**:

```
<cffunction name="mainFunction">
    <!--- some stuff --->
    <cfif someCondition>
        <!--- some other stuff --->
        <!--- finish off --->
        </cffunction>
    <cfelse>
        <!--- different stuff --->
        <cffunction name="theOtherFunction">
            <!--- different function --->
        </cffunction>
        </cffunction><!--- this is for the outer function --->
    </cfif>
```

That's... well it's not right.

What you want is this:

```
<cffunction name="mainFunction">
    <!--- some stuff --->
    <cfif someCondition>
        <!--- some other stuff --->
        <!--- different function --->
        <cfset something = theOtherFunction()>
    </cfif>
    <!--- finish off --->
</cffunction>

<cffunction nname="theOtherFuction">
    <!--- different stuff --->
</cffunction>
```

Note how each coding structure is self-contained.

I think you could benefit from reading through the CFML docs, and also some basic programming tutorials (any language) before you go too much further into it.

Also note: try to avoid using tag-based code for business logic: tags are really better suited for views, and it's a throw-back to earlier, ill-informed times that one can even *define* a function with tags. As a rule of thumb: tags for views; script for logic.

It's also important to read and understand the comments below. Even if your code was syntactically correct and could compile, it still wouldn't do what you want it to do because functions are compiled separately to the rest of the code, so your conditionality still wouldn't work.

Comment: *They do not execute when they are declared (ie: the `<cffunction>/</cffunction>`*  Well said.  To further the point, even ignoring the syntax errors in the original code - while CF might allow you to place a *complete* function definition within within cfif tags ie `<cfif something><cffunction ...>....</cffunction></cfif>` - you shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Leigh I haven't tested, but my recollection is that function declarations are extracted and compiled separately from the surrounding code, so conditionality like that would be pointless anyhow. I guess I should re-test this.

Comment: Yep, but that *is* the point (for lack of a better word) ;-) The original problem was not just that the code must be  "syntactically valid". CF will allow you to nest a *complete* function declaration inside a conditional .. which might be contributing to the asker's misunderstanding of how functions work. Even though CF might consider that type of code syntactically valid, as you say above - it is kind of pointless. The functions will be extracted and pre-compiled, so it is not actually doing what they think anyway.

Comment: @Leigh: Gotcha. Updated the answer to draw attention to this.